# DroneKit Cloud not found error page

Tags: dronekit

The link for the DroneKit Cloud docs takes me to a not found error page. Is this project still active? Or, has it been discontinued?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dronekit cloud has been discontinued. AFAIK only python and android projects from dronekit are alive with community support. [FlytBase](http://flytbase.com) is coming up with cloud platform soon. 
p.s. I'm one of the developers at FlytBase.